# What technology/protocol is used in iMessage app to show that user at other end is typing?

Tags: text, sms, ichat

[image]

In, iMessage when other party types, we see three dots on our end.

1. How is this implemented? 1a) Is this also implemented using
   [Apple Push Notification Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Push_Notification_service)  ?
2. I see same option in few other web chat applications. How is it
   done outside iMessage?

Comment: Actually the three dots are shown even if someone is *not* typing as it goes away after a while with no response. You may need to ask this on a developer discussion board tho...

Comment: I'm curious as to why you're asking?  If it's for a development reason then you'll get better answers on SE.

Comment: I'm a SDE and I'm preparing for system design interviews. Also, previously I tried to develop an app similar to Whatsapp. Hence this question came up in my mind out of curiosity

Comment: From https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask: „You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.“ So can you please edit the question to focus on the actual problem you are trying to solve? If this problem basically is "how do I develop this myself" please ask on StackOverflow or other sites focused on software development.

Comment: @nohillside If I had posted this in normal Stackoverflow, definitely it would have been downvoted. I have had experienced that before.

Comment: This may be very well the case (don't know the rules of SO so well but would assume that they prefer questions where some basic research has already been done by the user, and some basic coding has already been done). All I can see is that development-type questions are offtopic on AD, this also includes design-level questions like "how would I go on to develop this and that functionality".

Answer (score 1):

I know how it's done in a recent version of iMessage/Messages, but can't comment on other applications since there are many ways to do this.

The iMessage protocol allows an out-of-band "last message ID" to be tracked by Apple's servers for each conversation ID. This is separate from the end-to-end communication between parties. The "..." appears when the client application notices that the ID of the last message it has received is NOT the same as the conversation's last message ID according to Apple's servers.

APNS is not used for this unless it's a very recent development.

If, at some later point, the other party/parties stop preparing a new message, the ID held by Apple's servers will revert to the last message sent. Once the client app sees that the ID's match again, the "..." will disappear.

Another point: This will ONLY happen with "blue bubbles", since SMS does not provide a side channel for communication with the central authority (i.e. Apple's servers)

Comment: a) So,Does the Apple servers track each unique conversation at any given moment?
b) Does out-of-band means, the message that has left an user's device?

Comment: Apple's servers provide lookup and allow the end-to-end encryption to begin. The content of an iMessage conversation DOES NOT pass through Apple's servers. Apple doesn't know and can't even figure out what you said to each other unless somebody gives them a network trace.